# Wait till images are loaded inside angularjs factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I've created a small feature alowing users to search for movie titles. This does a JSON requests from tmdb.org which returns things like titles, dates and url's posters.

The controller:

```
    angular.module('movieSeat')
        .factory('moviesearchFactory', ['$http', '$q', '$rootScope', function ($http, $q, $rootScope) {

            var factory = {};

            function httpPromise(url) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    method: 'JSONP',
                    url: url
                })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data.results);
                    })
                    .error(function () {
                        deferred.reject();
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            }

            factory.getMovies = function (searchquery) {
                return httpPromise('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/' + 'search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4' + '&query=' + encodeURIComponent(searchquery) + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            }

            return factory;

        }]);
```

The factory:

```
    angular.module('movieSeat')
        .controller('moviesearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'moviesearchFactory', function ($scope, moviesearchFactory) {

            $scope.createList = function (searchquery) {
                $scope.loading = true;
                moviesearchFactory.getMovies(searchquery)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.movies = response;
                    })
                    .finally(function () {
                        $scope.loading = false;
                    });

            }

        }]);
```

The template:

```
    <div ng-controller="moviesearchCtrl" id="movieSearch">

        <div class="spinner" ng-show="loading">Loading</div>
        <input ng-model="searchquery" ng-change="createList(searchquery)" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }" />
        {{ search }}

        <ul>
            <li ng-if="movie.poster_path" ng-repeat="movie in movies | orderBy:'-release_date'">
                <span class="title">{{ movie.title }}</span>
                <span class="release_date">{{ movie.release_date }}</span>
                <img ng-src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300_and_h450_bestv2/{{ movie.poster_path }}" class="poster"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The problem with this feature is that the spinner class only waits for the requested data. But just loading some JSON doesn't take long, it's downloading the images from the api in the browser that takes a while.

This causes 2 things. First of the spinner is removed before the images are rendered in the browser and because the images are all loaded async it causes a waterfall effect.

The easiest way to resolve this problem would to delay the `.then` call in the controller until the images are downloaded for the user and then go into the `.finally` call.

But I can't find a way to create something like that. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know:

The idea is to use a directive to emit a render finished event:

```
dashboard.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit(attr.onFinishRender);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In the controller keep the event listener that wait for the image load promises:

```
    $scope.$on('dataLoaded', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
        // your code to check whether images has loaded
        var promises = [];
        var imageList = $('#my_tenants img');
        for(var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
            promises.push(imageList[i].on('load', function() {}););
        }
        $q.all(promises).then(function(){
            // all images finished loading now
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    });
```

and in the html side:

```
<div id = "my_tenants">
    <div ng-repeat="tenant in tenants" on-finish-render="dataLoaded">
        // more divs
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't get it quite working but your suggestion of using promises led met to the answer. Found a plunkr somewhere that kinda did what I wanted. So I adapted it > http://plnkr.co/edit/assAAiz0NnV1bt7ASY9z?p=preview and does what I want :).

Comment: cool.. in my code above I'm waiting for the DOM to be updated too to set the image promises... :)

Comment: I didn't get this part though `var imageList = $('#my_tenants img');` are you using a jquery selector to fill the array of imageList?

Comment: selects all the images that are in the ng-repeat where the data is loading... in your code it would look `$('#movieSearch img')`